# best data persistance for NSObject subclass

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm fairly new to iOS development, so I need some advise.

I'm working on a project (creating a character sheet app for an upcoming table top RPG), and I seem to have put the cart a bit before the horse.

I've already created a subclass of NSObject called characterClass that holds everything I need for a single instance of the character sheet. It also has methods to calculate derived information. I have 2 more classes storing abilities, and have them in NSArrays in the characterClass. Now that it's working, I need to work on data persistance, and storing/retrieving multiple characters.

I'm thinking, of using Core Data, creating a separate entity that matches my characterClass, and having a characterClass init method that pulls the data out of Core Data and puts it into the current instance of characterClass. That seems a bit obtuse to me, (implementing a class separate from the entity) but maybe it's a good way to do it.

I would eventually like to set up dropbox syncing for this information, so whatever I do I would like to have compatible with that. (Core Data with XML files as the backend?)

What would be the best method for something like this?

Comment: Check out AFIncrementalStore https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than just pull the data out of Core Data and use it to create your character class, you could just tweak your character class so that it is an NSManagedObject subclass. That way you are storing your objects directly in Core Data

Comment: Okay. I think I just need to learn more about Core Data to do that. Do I just create an entity with attributes that match the class, and point the entity to that class?

If so, do I set up NSArrays as transformable, or do I create new entities for all the arrays, and create relationships for them?

Comment: Okay, I got the Arrays figured out, and have switched my application over. I ended up backing up the old class files, recreating it with the entity designer, then creating the subclasses with the automatic creator. I then copied the old methods I had in the classes over to the new classes. The hardest part was wrapping my head around Core Data.